# How to add file value with jQuery serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sorry for the weird title of the question.

I am trying to process a form using jQuery ajax which contain a file.

This is what I am trying to use..

```
<script>
     var file_data = $('#qfile').prop('files')[0];   
     var form_data = new FormData();
     form_data.append('file', file_data);// 
     var data = $(this).serialize();
     // Here is the problem. I sucessfully sent the file alone but I want to 
     //send all the form input values using serialize() and add formData too

</script>
```

I want to send the file and also all the input serialize()

Here is my ajax part...

```
<script>
   $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'ajax/ajax-reg.php',
            data : form_data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

</script>
```

Comment: What do you get in $_FILE array when you post?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I want to send all the form input values using serialize() and add formData too

In this case `serialize()` won't help you, but there is a better way. Simply provide the `form` DOMElement to the `FormData()` constructor. Then all the data from the form fields (including the images) will be placed in to the FormData object. Try this:

```
var form_data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/ajax-reg.php',
    data: form_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function() {
        // handle response here...
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Using *jQuery*, you also can try something like this:

```
var postData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

postData.append("In", $("input[name=In]").val()); // usual input
postData.append("Txt", $("textarea[name=Txt]").text()); // textarea
postData.append("File", $("input[name=File]")[0].files[0]); // file

$.post('ajax/ajax-reg.php', postData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery (but this can be easily done via vanilla javascript too) to create a hidden text input after the file input. I then set the name of the new text input as the id of the file input it's associated with and set it's value (when a file is selected) to the filename. You can then use `$('form').serializeArray();` and return the name:value pairs of the hidden inputs that correspond to the file inputs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Dynamically create hidden text inputs for the file inputs' data
  // (create dynamically to avoid having re-write your entire html file)
 $('input:file').each( function(){
    $(this).after('<input type="text" readonly name="' + $(this).attr("id").replace("_", " ") + '" hidden value=""/>');
  });
  
  
  // When the user selects a file to be uploaded...
  $('input:file').change( function(){
  
    // If a file is selected set the text input value as the filename
    if($(this).get(0).files.length !== 0){
      $(this).next('input:text').val($(this).get(0).files[0].name);
    }
  
  });
  
  
  $("form").submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Clear previous data from results div
    $('#results').text("");
    
    // Serialize the form data
    var x = $('form').serializeArray();
    
    // Iterate through the array results and append
    // the data to the results div
    $.each(x, function(i, field) {
      var result  = '<span class="left">' + field.name + ' : </span>';
          result += '<span class="right">' + field.value + '</span><br>';
      $('#results').append(result);
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0; 
  width: auto;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.left, div.right, span.left, span.right { 
  display:block; 
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}
.rad { font-size: 14px; }
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }

#results { 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 40%; 
  line-height: 23px;
}
#results .left { 
  color: green; 
  text-align: right;
}
#results .right { 
  color: blue; 
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.clearfix { clear: both; }
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <div class="left">
      <label class="right" for="name">Name:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="file1">1st Pic:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="file2">2nd Pic:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="file3">3rd Pic:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="file4">4th Pic:</label><br>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <input class="left" type="text" name="Name" ><br>
      <select class="left" name="Gender">
        <option selected></option>
        <option>Unspecified</option>
        <option>Female</option>
        <option>Male</option>
      </select><br>
      
      <input class="left" type="file" accept="image/*" id="File_1"><br>
      <input class="left" type="file" accept="image/*" id="File_2"><br>
      <input class="left" type="file" accept="image/*" id="File_3"><br>
      <input class="left" type="file" accept="image/*" id="File_4"><br>
    </div>
  </form>
  
  <div id="results" class="right"></div>
  
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input form="myForm" type="submit" id="submit" value="Serialize Form" />
    <input form="myForm" type="reset" value="Reset Form" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
</body>
```